# Hide out of stock products in journal 2 theme of opencart

Tags: php, html, opencart

without the code , next page link show

i.stack.imgur.com/0Oniu.jpg

with the code the next page link does not show

i.stack.imgur.com/ljtmr.jpg

Help .

Code was written by ainosilva

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=62631#p381559

I fixed the issue by increase the number from 0 to 300

//$product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);
         $product_total=0;

but when i open second page i still find some out of stock products with incorrect url .

i.stack.imgur.com/tagBy.jpg

Help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do it with the theme but I scheduled a task to run a PHP file which changes the status of a product depending on its quantity. Here is the full script:

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "db_username";
$password = "db_password";
$dbname = "db_name";
$dbprefix = "oc_";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE " . $dbprefix . "product SET status = 1 WHERE quantity > 0";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$sql = "UPDATE " . $dbprefix . "product SET status = 0 WHERE quantity < 1";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach is to update the controller of opencart to update the statement to:

```
product.status = 1 && product.quantity >0;
```

Controller file is in `catalog->controller->product.php`